# Get edge vertex points then draw lines across the edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vertex

I am trying to get vertex points of a 3D Object then draw line with [`LineRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html). I want the lines to be drawn in order and not crossing through the middle of the model but the lines passes through the model. The image below shows what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, I am almost close to getting this done but the line is passing through the model.

The vertext points probably needs to be sorted. How can I fix this? How I can I make the points draw on the edge without passing through the Object?

Just attach the code below to a simple Cube to see the problem described above:

```
public class MapEdgeOutline : MonoBehaviour
{
    Color beginColor = Color.yellow;
    Color endColor = Color.red;
    float hightlightSize = 0.1f;

    void Start()
    {
        createEdgeLineOnModel();
    }


    void createEdgeLineOnModel()
    {
        EdgeVertices allVertices = findAllVertices();

        //Get the points from the Vertices
        Vector3[] verticesToDraw = allVertices.vertices.ToArray();

        drawLine(verticesToDraw);
    }

    //Draws lines through the provided vertices
    void drawLine(Vector3[] verticesToDraw)
    {
        //Create a Line Renderer Obj then make it this GameObject a parent of it
        GameObject childLineRendererObj = new GameObject("LineObj");
        childLineRendererObj.transform.SetParent(transform);

        //Create new Line Renderer if it does not exist
        LineRenderer lineRenderer = childLineRendererObj.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (lineRenderer == null)
        {
            lineRenderer = childLineRendererObj.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        }

        //Assign Material to the new Line Renderer
        //Hidden/Internal-Colored
        //Particles/Additive
        lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored"));


        //Set color and width
        lineRenderer.SetColors(beginColor, endColor);
        lineRenderer.SetWidth(hightlightSize, hightlightSize);

        //Convert local to world points
        for (int i = 0; i < verticesToDraw.Length; i++)
        {
            verticesToDraw[i] = gameObject.transform.TransformPoint(verticesToDraw[i]);
        }

        //5. Set the SetVertexCount of the LineRenderer to the Length of the points
        lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(verticesToDraw.Length + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < verticesToDraw.Length; i++)
        {
            //Draw the  line
            Vector3 finalLine = verticesToDraw[i];
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, finalLine);

            //Check if this is the last loop. Now Close the Line drawn
            if (i == (verticesToDraw.Length - 1))
            {
                finalLine = verticesToDraw[0];
                lineRenderer.SetPosition(verticesToDraw.Length, finalLine);
            }
        }
    }

    EdgeVertices findAllVertices()
    {
        //Get MeshFilter from Cube
        Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        Vector3[] meshVerts = mesh.vertices;

        //Get temp vert array
        float[][] meshVertsArray;
        meshVertsArray = new float[meshVerts.Length][];

        //Where to store the vertex points
        EdgeVertices allVertices = new EdgeVertices();
        allVertices.vertices = new List<Vector3>();

        int indexCounter = 0;

        //Get x,y,z vertex point
        while (indexCounter < meshVerts.Length)
        {
            meshVertsArray[indexCounter] = new float[3];

            meshVertsArray[indexCounter][0] = meshVerts[indexCounter].x;
            meshVertsArray[indexCounter][1] = meshVerts[indexCounter].y;
            meshVertsArray[indexCounter][2] = meshVerts[indexCounter].z;

            Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(meshVertsArray[indexCounter][0], meshVertsArray[indexCounter][1], meshVertsArray[indexCounter][2]);

            //Store the vertex pont
            allVertices.vertices.Add(tempVect);

            indexCounter++;
        }
        return allVertices;
    }
}

public struct EdgeVertices
{
    public List<Vector3> vertices;
}
```

Comment: As of solving this problem you can go several different ways (really depends if you will be doing cube meshes only or other more complex ones). However I have made [this video](https://streamable.com/ip6zl) to describe why the problem is occurring. In fact some of the lines that are drown are passing over each other. This is because the `findAllVertices` method indeed finds all vertices, but for all 6 planes of the mesh/cube. So instead of 8 vertices you are getting 24 total. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I believe I solved this long ago but forgot to post solution. I will when I have time

Comment: @Programmer Been busy for so long? Still no solution :)